# How to make Odoo 9 use an S3 bucket to store binary files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, odoo, odoo-9

I've got an Odoo instance (version 9) running on EC2. The Postgres database runs on RDS and, as far as I understand, binary files are not stored in the db but rather on the file system of the instance running the web server.

How can I tweak Odoo 9 so that it uses an S3 bucket for files storage (instead of the file system)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So... Had to implement the feature by myself. If anyone gets around here in the future, here [a link to my repo](https://github.com/tvanesse/odoo-s3).